# Avoiding a recursive re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Sending a react-redux action to an API to return posts when the user activates drag refresh or accesses the component for the first time.

This normally does not cause a problem as the FlatList would take directly from props and therefore not trigger a recursive loop. However, I need to format the data to fit the application and as a result, I pass the data through a series of methods before it hits the FlatList. This process is clashing with `componentDidUpdate` thus throwing the application into a loop of requests. Code below:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.posts !== this.props.posts){
        this.storePosts() //the problem is that when storeposts is called it is updating the props which then is calling store posts which is updating the props and so on and so on....
    }
}

  storePosts() { //the problem with this is that it changes the state
    this.props.fetchPosts() //this line is causing a continous request to rails
    let itemData = this.props.posts
    if (itemData !== this.state.currentlyDisplayed) {
        this.setState({ currentlyDisplayed: this.props.posts, items: itemData }, () => {
            this.setState({isLoading: false})
    });
  }
}

  formatItems = () => {
    const itemData = this.props.posts
    const newItems = [itemData]
    const numberOfFullRows = Math.floor(itemData.length / 3);
    let numberOfElementsLastRow = itemData.length - (numberOfFullRows * 3);
    while (numberOfElementsLastRow !== 3 && numberOfElementsLastRow !== 0) {
      newItems.push({ key: `blank-${numberOfElementsLastRow}`, empty: true });
      numberOfElementsLastRow++;
    }
    return this.setState({ newItems: newItems})
    // console.log(newItems.length, numberOfElementsLastRow)
  };

  renderItem = ({ item, type }) => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    if (item.empty === true) {
      return <View style={[styles.item, styles.itemInvisible]} />;
    } else {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPressIn={() => this.setState({ itemSelected: item.id })} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('View Post', {post: item})} key={item.id}>
          <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', height: undefined }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
          );
      }
  };

  onRefresh = () => {
      this.setState({refreshing: true})
      this.storePosts()
      this.setState({refreshing: false, currentlyDisplayed: this.props.posts})
  };

  render() {
      const { error: { vaultErrorMessage }} = this.props
      const { posts } = this.props

         <SafeAreaView>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.currentlyDisplayed}
              renderItem={this.renderItem}
              numColumns={3}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.refreshing} onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()} />}
              extraData={this.state.refresh}
            />
          </SafeAreaView>
        );
      }
  }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas to go about this better or solve the problem that would be great! I think I have been looking at the code for too long so I'm pretty dulled to thinking about how to solve....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest splitting the logic for updating the posts and storing the posts into two separate methods to avoid the infinite state update.

For example:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (shouldUpdate) { // some other condition
        this.updatePosts();
    }
    if (prevProps.posts !== this.props.posts){
        this.storePosts();
    }
}

updatePosts() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
}

storePosts() {
    let itemData = this.props.posts;
    if (itemData !== this.state.currentlyDisplayed) {
        this.setState({ currentlyDisplayed: this.props.posts, items: itemData }, () => {
            this.setState({isLoading: false})
        });
    }
}
```

You should also look into a better way to check if the posts have actually changed since the array may have changed but the content may have stayed the same. (Note that `[1, 2, 3] === [1, 2, 3]` evaluates to `false`). [`fast-deep-equal`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-deep-equal) is a good library for this, or you can come up with a custom solution.

Comment: Your array comment triggered the answer, changed the if statement to check the length of the props v the prev props, and as a result recursion stopped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use this approach, use [`static getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) instead of `componentDidUpdate`.

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or `null` to update nothing.
>
> This method exists for rare use cases where the state depends on changes in props over time. For example, it might be handy for implementing a `<Transition>` component that compares its previous and next children to decide which of them to animate in and out.

Comment: Thanks Corey. Another solution worked but looked into this!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it;

```
extraData={this.state.currentlyDisplayed}
```